# Getting a generic type class to check if its the same class type as the selected object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to create a generic method. Where the selected object in the asset window gets deleted on the button press of an editor window button, this is what it should look like in essence.

But I assume it can't check class type T as it's a generic type. Is there some way to still make this work?

```
    private void DeleteSelectedObject<T>(T selectedClass, List<T> selectedList)
    {
        var selectedObject = Selection.activeObject;

        if (selectedObject is T)
        {
            var path = AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(selectedObject);
            AssetDatabase.DeleteAsset(path);
                
            selectedList.Remove(selectedObject);
        }
        else
            Debug.LogError($"The selected object is not of type {selectedClass}");
    }
```

Comment: `...(T selectedClass, List<T> selectedList)`? Not sure what you are trying.

Comment: @nilsK So I'm getting the selected asset object in the Asset view. 
I'll be checking if that selectedObject is the same class type as a given class, in this case, the same class as selectedClass.
If this is the case, we'll get the path from that selectedObject in the Asset view. And delete that selectedObject on the found path.
Then we'll remove the selectedObject from a given list that is the same class type as the given selectedClass. And we'll cast the selectedObject to that selectedClass. Otherwise, it will give an error.
And if this doesn't work, we'll throw an error in the console.

Comment: The `is` keyword is used to determine if an instance is of a type.  The above usage is incorrect because you are not comparing against the type.  Instead use `if (selectedObject is T)`

Comment: @hijinxbassist I've edited the main post on what it looks like right now. The only thing that doesn't work yet is `selectedList.Remove((selectedClass)selectedObject);`. I've tried not casting it, casting it to T, casting it to selectedClass. But all don't work. It says: `Argument type 'UnityEngine.Object' is not assignable to parameter type 'T'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the selectedObject to T using the type T and store that cast object to a variable.

```
if (selectedObject is T castObject)
```

Now when you want to remove the item from your list, use the castObject variable.

```
if (selectedObject is T castObject)
{
    ...
    selectedList.Remove(castObject);
}
```